# Why if('k' in 42); throw exception while for('k' in 42); does not, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

From a language design perspective, why does

```
if ('k' in 42);
```

throw a `TypeError` exception while

```
for ('k' in 42);
```

does not?

I've read the following sections in ECMAScript spec:

- [11.8.7 The in operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.7)
- [12.6.4 The for-in Statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)

Can someone explain the rationale in having such an inconsistency?

Why can't expression `'k' in 42` in `if (...)` just evaluate to `false`?

Comment: BTW, it's the same in ES3.

Comment: Did you mean `for (k in 42)`? The string literal `'k'` is not even syntactically valid at that position.

Answer (score 2):

Re-read the in section.

```
If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
```

42 is not an object, it's a number

```
typeof 42 // 'number'
typeof new Number(42) // 'object'
```

for-in statement doesn't require an object, in fact it actually converts it to an object

```
Let obj be ToObject(experValue).
```

I don't think it's a reason behind this behaviour, it's probably a design flaw(inconsistency)

Comment: `Can some explain the consideration for these design?` That was the question: why the inconsistency?

Comment: @raina77ow "_I don't think it's a reason behind this behaviour, it's probably a design flaw(inconsistency)_"

Comment: Actually I don't see any inconsistency - the two expressions have totally different purpose and therefore totally different behaviour. The only flaw might have been that the same keyword, `in`, was used for both.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, something like that, but still, they could have converted it to an object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key here is the difference between 'operator' (`in`) and 'statement' (`for-in`). If you check the standard, you'll see that the latter only throw Errors when they're *written* incorrectly. The `with` case, which throws a *SyntaxError* (!) in the strict mode, is quite telling.

Apparently you cannot guess whether or not `for (var x in someExpr)` is written incorrectly unless you evaluate `someExpr` first.

Comment: What do you mean by `with`?